# NetBeans 8 stuggles to stop processes on Mac

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I run the latest version of NetBeans 8 on Mac 10.9.4 and Java 1.8.0_20.

I've noticed that NetBeans fail to stop processes. It's not only related to running stand alone application but also internal things like TomCat server. As an example, when I run a Maven Web app it will start the web server and deploy application correctly. The problem starts when I want to debug. NetBeans will wait forever or until I manually kill TomCat process.

Is there any workaround to this?